# Trouble accessing multidimension JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

My JSON output looks like this:
[image]

```
var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "generateplaylist.php",
                data: {
                    id: myClassID
                }
            });
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                        });
            request.done(function(data) {
                        console.log(data.songartist[1]);})
```

I can access that JSON output by changing it's parameter to GET and manually visiting the link. Whenever I try to access through post like this, I get an undefined error on the console.log line. I think it might be because of the fact I have a Json array and each key is it's own array, but I'm not so great once I leave the first dimension. I have tried many variations

```
data.songartist
data[songartist]
data[songartist][1]
```

etc.etc.

Here is the code for generateplaylist.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $json = array(
            'success'   => false,
            'songartist'    => '',
            'songname'  => ''
        );  

        $x = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $songartist[$x] = $row['songartist'];
             $songname[$x] = $row['songtitle'];
             $x++;
        }

        $json['success']        = true;
        $json['songartist']     = $songartist;
        $json['songname']       = $songname;

        echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `generateplaylist.php`.

Comment: Updated with that code, trimmed down a fair bit, I have multiple ajax requests running though and this code is setup identically to the rest except for the fact I am storing array's in the key's instead of single values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get he data with the following jQuery ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "generateplaylist.php",
    dataType: "json", // set explicit expected format as json
    data: {
        id: myClassID
    }
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data.songartist[1]);
})
.error(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

Data contains an element called `songartist` and this element is an array of strings so it is possible to reference it with `data.songartist[1]` to get the first string from the array.

*Tip*
In your php you can add items to an array without specifying an index. You could rewrite the code for the loop as

```
$songartist = []; // define array
$songname = []; // define array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $songartist[] = $row['songartist'];
     $songname[] = $row['songtitle'];
}
```

Comment: Good to know about the syntax, much cleaner written like that - I am pretty sure this will work now, I am getting an error instead of undefined. I keep getting 'parse error' which may be the reason I stopped including dataType:"json" in my requests. I am assuming that once I fix up my PHP code to parse out proper Json (not sure why its not) it will run. Thanks!

EDIT: And cheers for the array

Comment: Lol, so it turned out I had a non-UTF-8 character in one of my song URL's which was causing the parse error and was also the reason the code wasnt running until I declared the data type. The little things, glad I got to that conclusion though. Had to make a lot of small changes to accommodate it which I should have done already